# Mesh follows rig with an offset

Tags: animation, rigging

i am rigging a weapon, everything is working perfectly, everything is parented to weapon bone; trigger, maglock, magazine. Meshes and bones are following perfectly except bolt although i did the excact same thing after moving childed bolt bone the bolt mesh follows with an offset but bolt bone affect bolt mesh without a problem
[image]
[image: here is the rig]

[image: this is what happens when i move weapon bone]

this is what happens when i move weapon bone

Comment: Make sure that this piece is not doubly parented to the bone (through a basic parentage and through an Armature modifier). Or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: thank you for your answer it is doubly parented by multiple armature modifiers because otherwise the magazine doesnt follow the rig and i cannot rotate for trigger or maglocks, using multiple armature modifiers i was able to select every vertex group.

Comment: Double armature modifiers are not necessary.  I'd recommend posting a file demonstrating what you have, along with text saying why you made the decisions you made.  We should probably be able to provide advice on how to achieve your goals without creating double deforms like this (even though, presonally, I can't see them from your pic.)

Comment: Should you not parent the bolt bone to the weapon bone, and remove the bolt mesh from the weapon vertex group?

Comment: i added the blend file as well. no removing bolt vertex group after childing or parenting didnt work. i did exact same adjustments for magazine trigger and maglock but only bolt has this problem

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have this issue is that your bolt mesh is weighted at 1 in two  vertex groups: weapon and bolt:

[image]

Remove it from the weapon vertex group and problem solved. To do this, you can <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into Edit Mode, hit <kbd>L</kbd> while hovering the bone mesh to select it, then in the Vertex Groups panel, select the weapon group and hit the Remove button.

On a different note: Keeping things simple is always preferable: fewer factors for issues, faster to use, edit and maintain, ... In that regard:

1. You do NOT need to make multiple armature deform modifiers with specific groups. One armature modifier with just the vertex groups checkbox enabled is more than enough.
2. You also should have a root bone at the top of the bone hierarchy, especially if you export outside of Blender where some exchange formats and software might give you trouble for not having one.
3. You do not need Child Of constraints on the weapon parts bones to parent them to a bone that could already be a parent in the first place. These kind of constraint are not for replacing a hierarchy, their purpose is to give alternative when needed. Instead, parent these bones to the weapon bone, and use Child Of constraints to parent these bones to external things, like hands, **only when needed**.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer now it is fixed. I parented all bones to the weapon bone and i will use child of modifier for left hand on mag and bolt for reload animation. I really appriciate your answer thank you for taking your time.